# Easy way to copy all values from one table to another with an extra column

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there an easy way to do something like this?

```sql
insert into table1
select *, 'extra stuff' as extra_field
from table2
```

I know when the columns match, I can just do a

```sql
insert into table1
select *
from table2
```

But in my case, table1 has an extra field that I want to populate. Is there a simple way to do that without having to manually type out all the existing fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the table you are selecting from an alias (`t`, for example), and you can then select all columns from this table using `t.*`, along with any extra columns you want to add.

Here's an example.  I ran the below on my Oracle 18c XE database:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table2 (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c INTEGER);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE table1 (a INTEGER, b INTEGER, c INTEGER, d INTEGER);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO table2 (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c, d)
  2  SELECT t.*, 4
  3    FROM table2 t;

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM table1;

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3          4
```

Comment: You've saved me so much typing. Thank you, my friend! I was able to do it even without the (a, b, c, d) portion as long as I used the t.*